# LSTM is not optimizing the Loss

Tags: optimization, pytorch, lstm, reinforcement-learning, backpropagation

I'm working on a reinforcement learning project where I'm using Mini_grid as a toy environment to check whether my idea is working. I'm using a convolutional neural network followed by an LSTM network. The summary of the network architecture is [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR2kh.png). I'm using PyTorch and the code I used to create the network is as follows,

```
class RRLSTM(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, config):
    super(RRLSTM, self).__init__()
    
    #Getting the features from the config file
    cnn_features = config["CNN"]
    lstm_features = config["LSTM"]
    mlp_features = config["MLP"]
    
    #Getting the cnn features
    nonlinearity = torch.relu
    input_channels = cnn_features["input_channels"]
    channels = cnn_features["channels"]
    kernel_sizes = cnn_features["kernel_sizes"]
    strides = cnn_features["strides"]
    paddings = cnn_features["paddings"]
    use_maxpool = cnn_features["use_maxpool"]
    
    #Getting MLP features
    fc_input_size = cnn_features["fc_input_size"]
    fc_hidden_sizes = mlp_features["fc_hidden_sizes"]
    embed_size = mlp_features["embed_size"]
    
    #Getting the LSTM features
    n_units = lstm_features["n_units"]
    input_size = lstm_features["input_size"]
    
    #Constructing CNN layer
    if paddings is None:
        paddings = [0 for _ in range(len(channels))]
    assert len(channels) == len(kernel_sizes) == len(strides) == len(paddings)
    in_channels = [input_channels] + channels[:-1]
    post_activation_fns = [identity for _ in range(len(strides))]
    ones = [1 for _ in range(len(strides))]
    if use_maxpool:
        post_activation_fns = [torch.nn.MaxPool2d(max_pool_stride) for max_pool_stride in strides]
        strides = ones
    activation_fns = [nonlinearity for _ in range(len(strides))]
    conv_layers = [CNNLayer(input_channels=ic, output_channels=oc,
                            kernel_size=k, stride=s, padding=p, activation_fn=a_fn, post_activation_fn=p_fn)
                   for (ic, oc, k, s, p, a_fn, p_fn) in zip(in_channels, channels, kernel_sizes, strides, paddings,
                                                            activation_fns, post_activation_fns)]
    #CNN_Linear layer
    linear_layer = Linear(fc_input_size, input_size)
    
    #Constructing MLP layers
    lstm_fc_layers = MLP(
        input_size=n_units,
        output_size=1,
        hidden_sizes=fc_hidden_sizes,
        hidden_activation=nonlinearity,
        output_activation=identity
    )
    
    #Constructing the action embedding layer
    action_embedding_layers = Embed(
        embed_dim=embed_size
    )
    
    #Constructing the LSTM layer
    lstm_layer = LSTM(
        fc_input_size = input_size, 
        embed_dim = embed_size, 
        n_units = n_units
    )
    
    #Constructing the network
    self.model = Network(conv_layers, linear_layer, action_embedding_layers, lstm_layer, lstm_fc_layers)
    

def forward(self, input):
    return self.model.forward(input)
```

The config details are as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZeoY.png),

I'm follwing the idea from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.07857.pdf) . The loss functions are the weighted summation of two other loss function as in [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghb9t.png), Where 'g' is the label for the dequence of data and 'g_t' is the label at each time of the prediction of LSTM. 'g_T' is the terminal preditction of the sequence. Since the batch contain variable length trajectory, I'm using a mask to eliminate the padded part while calculating. The code for loss function is as follows,

```
    def calculate_loss(self, predicted_G0, returns, length):
    
        if not torch.is_tensor(returns):
           returns = torch.tensor(returns)
           returns = returns.to(device)
        
        # B x L
        all_timestep_loss = self.mse_loss(predicted_G0, returns.repeat(1, 
                                          predicted_G0.size(1)))
        
        # Create the smask
        self.mask = torch.zeros_like(all_timestep_loss)
        for l_num, l in enumerate(length):
            self.mask[l_num, :l] = 1
            
        #Multiplying with the self.mask to avoid the padded sequence
        all_timestep_loss = all_timestep_loss * self.mask

        # Average for each sequence
        self.mean_all_timestep_loss_along_sequence = all_timestep_loss.sum(1) / self.mask.sum(1)
        
        # Average across the batch
        mean_loss = self.mean_all_timestep_loss_along_sequence.mean()
        aux_loss = self.continuous_pred_factor * mean_loss
    
        #all_time_step_loss_np = all_timestep_loss.detach().cpu().numpy()
        len = length[:] - 1
        all_timestep_loss_indexed = all_timestep_loss[range(predicted_G0.size(0)), len]
    
        # LSTM is mainly trained on getting the final prediction of g0 right.
        main_loss = all_timestep_loss_indexed.mean()

        # LSTM update and loss tracking
        lstm_loss = main_loss + aux_loss
    
    return lstm_loss, main_loss, aux_loss
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

EDIT:

I discovered that the network is suffering from a vanishing gradient problems as evident from the first[image: first] CNN layer weight gradient and the last [image: last] linear layer weight gradient. I'm using ReLu activations. I'll reduce the network depth and see if there is any change. Is there any alternative way to get rid of the problem in this setting